# excelが重い(vlookupなどの多用)

Tags: excel

やりたいこと：
excelが重いので、
重くならないようにしたい

サイズ：50000行✕50列程度

excelの状況
・メインのシートが１つ
・メインシート上の各セルにおいて、
　別シートの表を利用しvlookupを使って
　対応する他の情報に変換している
・メインのシートの各行は、
　一つ一つの顧客情報を表す。顧客情報には住まいの県、住所、氏名などの属性a,b,c,dが付属しており、顧客は同姓同名が存在するため、顧客の属性a〜dをすべて横に繋げた情報をもとに顧客を一通りに特定している。この横につなげた情報を保持するための新たな列をメインのシートの表に追加で1行最右に追加している。別シートでも顧客を表すabcdが結合された列があり、別シート上ではこのabcd結合情報と対応する属性efghがあり、それを別シートのすべての行からvlookupで検索して対応するe〜hの情報を持ってきている。
・メインシートの各顧客ごとの上記の情報を利用して、最終的に顧客の目視での異常性判定をすることがこのexcelの目的
・マクロは利用していない
・察するにvlookupで重くなっている、それ以外に、countifも少しだけ利用している

問題点：
・ファイルが重すぎて、少し編集して保存だけで時間がかかる(PCの環境によっては1時間程度)
・表を編集しようにも、少し列を消すなどするとexcel標準の大量に処理を行う操作のメッセージが出現し、メモリが不足して落ちる

試したこと：
・いくつか調べ、vlookupのtrueでの処理の高速化を試したくても、ファイルの更新だけでも異様に時間がかかるため、手を焼いている

Comment: ファイルサイズはいくですか？PCのメモリはいくつですか？

Comment: 文章での説明はわかりづらいです。可能な範囲で、シート名、シート毎の列名を列挙していただくと、問題点を掴みやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: ファイルサイズ40MB,PCメモリ8GBです

Comment: 保存の際は、cpu使用率が一気に100%になります

Answer (score 3):

[Excel のパフォーマンス: パフォーマンスの問題を最適化するヒント](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions#use-index-and-match-or-offset-instead-of-vlookup)がまとめられていますので参照してください。特に「VLOOKUP の代わりに INDEX と MATCH または OFFSET を使用する」が効果がありそうです。

`VLOOKUP`を多用されているとのことですが、`VLOOKUP`は指定範囲を検索した上で該当行の指定列の値を抽出する関数です。同一行に対して列ごとに何度も検索を繰り返している部分は相当な無駄となります。
これは`MATCH`と`INDEX`に分解することができます。つまり、各行について`MATCH`で対象行を検索しセルに保存します。同一行はその結果を使用して`INDEX`で必要な列を取り出すことができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。頂いた方法を試してみます

Comment: ほとんど速度は変わりませんでした

Comment: @keitotanki 具体的なコードを提示してください。

Answer (score 1):

Excelの数式-計算方法の設定を「手動」にしてどうでしょうか？
数式の更新が必要になった場合に手動で更新すれば良いかと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 既に手動にしています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。手動に関して記述してなくて申し訳ないです。